# Make a list of lists a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<List<CustomType>>`. Each `List<CustomType>` contains only 1 `CustomType`. How do I make my `List<List<CustomType>>` a `List<CustomType>`?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - in order to properly research this question you'd have to know what to call this (how do I *flatten* collections in C#), and if you know what to call it, well, first result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, you can use `SelectMany()`. Given something like this:

```
List<List<CustomType>> listOfLists = Init() ;
```

You can simply say:

```
List<CustomType> flattenedList = listOfLists.SelectMany().ToList() ;
```

but, since you know that each of nested lists contains a single item, you could simply say something like either of these:

- `List<CustomType> flattenedList = listOfLists.Select( x => x.First() ).ToList() ;`
- `List<CustomType> flattenedList = listOfLists.Select( x => x[0] ) ;`